# Does Allah forgive someone who commit adultry?

Tags: allah, sin, punishment, forgiveness

In Islam we are told that we should ask Allah for forgiveness no matter how many sins we have and He will forgive us if our touba is sincere. There was also and instance when somebody ask for a lady's hand in marriage and another person told the man who was proposing that the girl had committed adultery in the past. Then the Prophet (saw) told the other man that he should not have said that because the girl was ashamed of what she had done and had asked Allah for forgiveness.

However in Islam if a person commit adultery, they have to be stoned to death. Then how can this person ask for forgiveness?

This also applied to other sins where a death penalty applies. Even for someone who steals something, their hand has to be chopped off, so does this mean they will not be punished for stealing in there hereafter because they have already been punished for their mistake? After all Allah is Most Merciful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the name of Allah the most Gracious the most Merciful,

> And those who accuse chaste women and then do not produce four witnesses - lash them with eighty lashes and do not accept from them testimony ever after. And those are the defiantly disobedient - 24:4

First, let us start about the punishment of adultery because it seems that you have a "not totally right idea" about it.

First thing, stoning until death is only for those who commit adultery while they're married. Getting whipped 100 times is for those who commit adultery when they're unmarried.

Now, the most important part about it. This punishment MUST NOT and CANNOT be implemented unless there are four witnesses (refer to surat al noor verse 4 at the top). It is not just "cannot be implemented", the person should not be accused of adultery without four witnesses, and if someone accuses a person for adultery without four witnesses, the one who accused should be whipped eighty times (refer also to surat al nur verse 4 at the top). It is not just to witness an unmarried couple sleeping together. The witness must have seen them during sexual intercourse for the witness to be counted.

From the previous part, we can conclude that for someone to be eligible for the punsihment must have done it in public (how on earth would there be 4 witnesses unless in public). That's why this punishment wasn't implemented at the times of the Prophet much due to it's extreme and strict requirements (it was done between 2 or 3 times as far as i can remember).

Now for the matter of forgiveness. If the person has committed adultery and only Allah knows, and there are no 4 witnesses, then of course, and definitely he/she would be granted forgiveness after Allah's will, as Allah is the most Forgiving and most Merciful.

Last but not least, by Allah's perfect mercy, any punishment (islamic) for any crime (adultery, stealing etc.) in this world will be sufficient enough so that the one who committed the crime would be free from the punishment at the hereafter. That's one of the main reasons for punishments anyways.

I hope that answers your question, and Allah knows best!

Comment: It would be better if you could post the Ayats in question instead of saying 'refer to this ayat'. Some people either don't have time or have proxy-restrictions, restricting them from referring to the mentioned ayats etc.

Comment: Yep you're right, I edited my answer. @SorrelVesper

Answer (score 1):

Assalamualaikum,

It is important to know that giving the rulings such as chopping off hands etc can only be given when the rule of law is applied equally to everyone. Be it rich or poor, the same law applies. Also by consensus of ulema it is believed that one who commits a sin such as one you mentioned above should keep it between them and Allah and not make it public. It is upto Allah the most just to judge on it on the day of judgement. If say, such a nation exists that applies rule of law equally to rich and poor, black or white and he/she was given the punishment then that will be written off of their record and they won't be punished again in the hereafter.

Also the story you had mentioned is from the time of Omar R.A when a father asks whether he should reveal about his daughter's past while she had repented to Allah for her sins and Omar R.A advises against it and commands him to keep it a secret.

I hope that Allah gives the strength to whoever this question is for to stay away from such sin and he grant them forgiveness for the true taubah they made and guide us all to straight path.

FYI, I am narrating what the scholar in my masjid said about this issue. He is a learned scholar and i am not and Allah knows best.